# DIG connection times out DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, nslookup, dig

I'm at home (COMCAST is the ISP).  I can run nslookup and resolve IPs fine.  When I run dig I receive "connection timed out: no servers could be reached"

I'm going to fireup a network trace but wondering if anyone else has seen this.  Windows 7 is the OS, just doing some DNS lookups.

Comment: Since when does there exist a `dig` under Windows 7?

Comment: @mailq As long as Nicholas Fong has been providing [great Win32 binaries](http://members.shaw.ca/nicholas.fong/dig/).

Comment: Migrate to http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you copy resolv.conf from your dig directory to your %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc directory? If not, that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be an issue with the firewall blocking the connection coming back from DNS. You could try to disable the firewall and test the dig again to see if it succeeds.

Comment: If nslookup works, then it can't be a firewall issue.

Comment: @mailq actually, it could be a firewall issue, if nslookup does a query over UDP and dig does it over TCP (which is often what happens, because dig is requesting more information than a single packet response will allow).

Answer (score 0):

This is either a TCP/UDP blocking issue or an IPv6 issue. Do you have a firewall? It might be blocking the TCP DNS queries that dig is generating. Alternately, it might be attempting to do v6 lookups (or might be attempting v4 lookups when v6 are the only ones being allowed through). But I'd put my money on TCP being blocked for DNS, which dig often uses because it requests much more information in a query than just the domain name->IP mapping.